# C++ 11 unordered_map.find exception

Tags: c++, exception, math, find, unordered-map

latest simplified code, crashed in emplace call: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
struct test
{
    int x;
    int *y;
    map<string, uintptr_t> m;
};

int main ()
{

    int x=11,y=22;
    void *x1 = &x, *y1=&y;

    test *t1 = static_cast<test*>(calloc(1,sizeof(test)));
    t1->m.emplace(string("x"),reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(x1));
    t1->m.emplace(string("y"),reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(y1));

  return 0;
}
```

================ below is the previous code crash=====

C++11 unordered_map find calls throws:
Program terminated with signal 8, Arithmetic exception.
changed around void * and uintptr_t in linux C++ code. The type uintptr_t is for me to cast to / from void * pointer due to history reason.

```
unordered_map<string, uintptr_t> channels;
...
auto itr = channels.find(string("abc"));
```

It crashed for the first call where the map is empty. It compiles.
GDB dump:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000047457d in std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator() (this=0x2ad198001aa0, __num=8205015523586275093, __den=0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable_policy.h:345
#1  0x0000000000474c83 in std::__detail::_Hash_code_base, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>::_M_bucket_index (
    this=0x2ad198001aa0, __c=8205015523586275093, __n=0) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1108
#2  0x000000000047493a in std::_Hashtable, std::allocator >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >::_M_bucket_index (this=0x2ad198001aa0, __k="nuance90-mrcp1", __c=8205015523586275093) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable.h:593
#3  0x00000000004747b0 in std::_Hashtable, std::allocator >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >::find (this=0x2ad198001aa0, __k="nuance90-mrcp1") at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable.h:1024
#4  0x00000000004745f5 in std::unordered_map, std::equal_to, std::allocator > >::find (this=0x2ad198001aa0, __x="abc")
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:543
```

Comment: A minimal complete example program that demonstrates the problem would be useful.

Comment: @Shawn `[mcve]` expands to [mcve]. Very handy, but wait! [There's more!](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @Charlie This just means there is a bug somewhere in your code. If your code is small then you can post that. If you have a lot of code you need to make it a reasonable size (hence the comment for mcve). In the processes of doing this (simplifying) you will probably find the problem. Which is why we ask people to do it.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for reply. I got simplified and now it crashed in emplace call. It compiles.

Comment: `calloc` function only allocates memory, constructors of member data are not called, so `m` is not initialized properly, call `test* t = new test;`.

Comment: the STL member in a c struct is my addition to legacy code, which used calloc.

Comment: @Charlie nevertheless, the c++ standard requires that placement new is called on t1 in order for there to be a c++ object at that address. Bear that in mind if you get strange behaviour when enabling optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: c function calloc get you fixed size of memory, if you have a STL container inside a c struct, & used c calloc function, the program may not be able to increase size. Here is the code that worked, please see the difference: the contained STL inside a c struct now become a pointer.

```
#include <utility>      // std::pair, std::make_pair
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
struct test
{
    int x;
    int *y;
    map<string, uintptr_t> *m;
};

int main ()
{
    int x=11,y=22;
    void *x1 = &x, *y1=&y;

    test *t1 = static_cast<test*>(calloc(1,sizeof(test)));
    t1->m = new map<string, uintptr_t>();
    t1->m->emplace(string("x"),reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(x1));
    t1->m->emplace(string("y"),reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(y1));

    cout<<"====== retrive the map in a calloc memory area==="<<endl;
    auto itr = t1->m->find(string("x"));
    if(itr != t1->m->end())
    {
        int *i = reinterpret_cast<int*>(itr->second);
        cout<<"found x="<<*i<<endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: as @rafix07 mentioned, the STL container constructor not called by calloc.

Comment: This works, but adds unnecessary memory management requirements to the program. All of the `test::m` members now must be manually deleted. Avoid doing this.

Comment: Agree with you. @user4581301. I am working on legacy c code

Comment: Inserting C++ code into C code is likely a bad idea. Stick to one language, or at least one language per source file.